# Bound on spectral radii

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory, adjoint-operators, spectral-radius

Let $L$ be some linear and compact operator on some Hilbert space. And denote by $L^*$ the adjoint operator.

I need to bound for some $c>0$:

$$
\left\|(L^*L+c I)^{-\frac{1}{2}}L^*\right\|\leq1
$$
what i tried was

$$
\left\|(L^*L+c I)^{-\frac{1}{2}}L^*\right\|^2= \left\|L(L^*L+c I)^{-1}L^*\right\|
$$

However from here I get stuck. I think I need some functional calcul analysis to understand how this works ? I would understand it if

$$
\left\|L(L^*L+c I)^{-1}L^*\right\|\,\, (?=?)\,\, \left\|L^*L(L^*L+c I)^{-1}\right\|
= \sup_{\sigma\in r(L^*L)}\left\|\sigma(\sigma+c)^{-1}\right\|\leq1
$$
However in general the operators do not commute under the operator norm or do they ?
I would be very glad if someone could tell me what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to use is the C$^*$-identity $\|T^*T\|=\|T\|^2=\|TT^*\|$. So
$$
\|(L^*L+cI)^{-1/2}L^*\|^2=\|(L^*L+cI)^{-1/2}L^*L(L^*L+cI)^{-1/2}\|
=\|L^*L(L^*L+cI)^{-1}\|\leq1.
$$
Once you get an $L^*L$ things do commute. And now $L^*L$ is positive, so you can use functional calculus, the spectral theorem, or other techniques to show that last inequality.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Glad I could help. The result holds for arbitrary bounded $L$, again with the last inequality proven by the spectral theorem or functional calculus.